# Perfect match between users with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm looking to make a perfect match between users using mongoose.

Here is an example of a schema:

```
username: "Nicolas",
fruitiwant:["apple", "orange"]
fruitihave: ["banana"]
```

I want to have a json that displays users who have a perfect match. **User A** wants the fruit that **user B** has. **User B wants** the fruit that **user A has**.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If user A wants 5 fruit and has 1 fruit, and user B wants 1 fruit and has 1 fruit ( both of them user A matches ) does this constitute a perfect match? or both sides need to be fully happy ?

Comment: Hi Tom. Yes. We have a perfect match between these two users. We exchange a fruit for another fruit.

Comment: Absolutely not Robert.
I'm curious as to which method to use, as I'm a beginner on mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we can do is use `$lookup` to match all users from the collection that suffice the condition, we then just have to group to eliminate duplicate couples, like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      let: {
        ihave: "$bookihave",
        iwant: "$fruitiwant",
        id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $ne: [
                    "$_id",
                    "$$id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $gt: [
                    {
                      $size: {
                        "$setIntersection": [
                          "$$ihave",
                          "$fruitiwant"
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $gt: [
                    {
                      $size: {
                        "$setIntersection": [
                          "$$iwant",
                          "$bookihave"
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    0
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            username: 1,
            
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "perfect"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$perfect"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      matchedUserNames: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $gt: [
              "$username",
              "$perfect.username"
            ]
          },
          [
            "$perfect.username",
            "$username",
            
          ],
          [
            "$username",
            "$perfect.username"
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$matchedUserNames"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/akOyF4Y-AjH)